# Simulating Inertial Scrolling for an object

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have an object that I need to drag and simulate inertial scrolling.

This is what I have so far that is working sluggish.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    self.lastTouch = touchLocation;
    self.lastTimestamp = event.timestamp;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // how much it scrolled vertically (it is a table view, no need to scroll horizontally)
    CGFloat deltaY = currentLocation.y - self.lastTouch.y;

    // move the container (that is the object I want to implement the inertial movement)
    // to the correct position
    CGPoint posActual = self.container.position; 
    posActual.y = posActual.y + deltaY;
    [self.container setPosition:posActual];


    // calculate the movement speed
    NSTimeInterval deltaTime = event.timestamp - self.lastTimestamp;
    self.speedY = deltaY / deltaTime;

    self.lastTouch = currentLocation;
    self.lastTimestamp = event.timestamp;

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGFloat tempoDecay = 0.4f;

    CGPoint finalPosition = self.container.position;
    finalPosition.y = finalPosition.y + (self.speedY * tempoDecay);

    // move the object to the final position using easeOut timing...

}
```

This is what I see: I swipe it. When I lift my finger, it accelerates and then stops abruptly. I have logged speedY values and the values are immense, like 720! (720 pixels per second?)

I cannot use UIScrollView or other method provided by Apple. It is an object that has to scroll with inertia by itself. Thanks.

Comment: You had several good comments on the old question. Don't just delete it and start again.

Comment: I have asked people to check my code, not to give advice of hacks that I could use to create a lame code that could make it work by dubious means. Obviously what I have asked is plausible and can be done. So, instead of down voting questions and making not helpful  comments like your latest one, you could try to answer what I have asked. If you don't have the knowledge or don't want to help, let other people more professional try. Thanks.

Comment: I down voted for the fact that you deleted your old question to get rid of comments that you had decided weren't useful and then created a new question. What was suggested is not a hack at all and if you follow the advice given and watch the relevant WWDC videos you'll find that the Apple dev team actually use the same technique.

Comment: I have watched those 2 spritekit videos in the past and did not remember seeing that. After your advice, I have scrubbed both videos (because I do not have time now to spend 2 hours watching them) and found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i implement this inertial scrolling ( of a SKSpriteNode object filled with many sprites vertically to simulate a vertical scrolling selection ) by adding 'inertial braking' in the scene's update method

```
// add the variables as member variables to your class , setup with initial values on your init 
  SKSpriteNode *mList // this is the sprite node that will be our scroll object
  mTouching = NO;         // BOOL
  mLastScrollDist = 0.0f; // float
```

in your touchesBegan , change the mTouching to YES , indicating a touch is in effect..

in your touchesMoved , calculate mLastScrollDist = previousLocation.y -  currentlocation.y , then add it to the y position of mList (mList.y += mLastScrollDist)

in your touchesEnded , change mTouching to NO

and lastly in the scene's update method , calculate the braking inertial effect

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (!mTouching)
    {
        float slowDown = 0.98f;

        if (fabsf(mLastScrollDist) < 0.5f)
            slowDown = 0;

        mLastScrollDist *= slowDown;
        mList.y += mLastScrollDist; // mList is the SKSpriteNode list object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

touchesMoved calls many times during your swipe. And the distance between two points of each call is 15-30 pixels. Let swipe lasts 0.5 seconds and the method is called 10 times. speedY  = 30/0.05 = 600.

Also taken into account only the last "touchesMoved speed". Maybe you need to calculate the average speed?

Comment: I have added an average calculation but the speed reduction was negligible. What is happening is that what should be a deceleration is not. In fact, when I lift the finger the object accelerates then decelerates and stops abruptly.